# Vault kv secrets and nomad jobs

Tags: vault, nomad

I am creating a nomad job that accesses vault kv secrets. At the moment I managed to create the policies, and a role, but I can't make it consume the secret.

This would be my nomad job:

```
job "http-echo" {
  datacenters = ["ikerdc2"]

  group "echo" {
    count = 1
    task "server" {
      driver = "docker"
      vault {
        policies = ["access-tables"]
      }
      template {
        data = <<EOT
          {{ with secret "kv/me" }}
          NAME ="{{ .Data.data.name }}"
          {{ end }}
      EOT
        destination = "echo.env"
        env         = true
      }
      
      config {
        image = "hashicorp/http-echo:latest"
        args  = [
          "-listen", ":8080",
          "-text", "Hello World!",
        ]
      }

      resources {
        network {
          mbits = 10
          port "http" {
            static = 8080
          }
        }
      }

      service {
        name = "http-echo"
        port = "http"

        tags = [
          "urlprefix-/http-echo",
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have created a vault server with the command `vault server -dev`
I have a kv secret named "me" and inside it's just like

```
{
 "name" = "Hello Iker"
}
```

And the policies are like this:

```
# Allow creating tokens under "nomad-cluster" role. The role name should be
# updated if "nomad-cluster" is not used.
path "auth/token/create/nomad-cluster" {
  capabilities = ["update"]
}

# Allow looking up "nomad-cluster" role. The role name should be updated if
# "nomad-cluster" is not used.
path "auth/token/roles/nomad-cluster" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}

# Allow looking up the token passed to Nomad to validate the token has the
# proper capabilities. This is provided by the "default" policy.
path "auth/token/lookup-self" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}

# Allow looking up incoming tokens to validate they have permissions to access
# the tokens they are requesting. This is only required if
# `allow_unauthenticated` is set to false.
path "auth/token/lookup" {
  capabilities = ["update"]
}

# Allow revoking tokens that should no longer exist. This allows revoking
# tokens for dead tasks.
path "auth/token/revoke-accessor" {
  capabilities = ["update"]
}

# Allow checking the capabilities of our own token. This is used to validate the
# token upon startup.
path "sys/capabilities-self" {
  capabilities = ["update"]
}

# Allow our own token to be renewed.
path "auth/token/renew-self" {
  capabilities = ["update"]
}
path "kv/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "update", "read"]
}
```

And the role is like this:

```
{
  "allowed_policies": "access-tables",
  "token_explicit_max_ttl": 0,
  "name": "nomad-cluster",
  "orphan": true,
  "token_period": 259200,
  "renewable": true
}
```

This are the errors I get when I run the job:

> Missing: vault.read(kv/me) Template failed: vault.read(kv/me):
> vault.read(kv/me): Error making API request. URL: GET
> http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/kv/me Code: 403. Errors: * 1 error occurred:
>
> - permission denied

If someone could help me with that it would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your post, I don't see the contents of the `access-tables` policy itself. That ACL policy must have the following rules:

```
path "kv/data/me" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

The permissions that the `nomad-cluster` policy from the documentation requires are for Nomad to create tokens in Vault for the policies that you list in the `vault` stanzas of your Nomad jobs. Adding the ability for that policy to read KV will not help. Instead, the policy in the `vault` stanza in your job, `access-tables`, needs that permission.

Comment: I have added the data in the path but still not working. How do I add the permission in the vault stanza of my job? I have tried many things and the official documentation is not working for me.